# autofs mounts entire direct map

Tags: nfs, autofs

I've got a auto.master with an indirect map and a direct map.

```
 /home /etc/auto.home --timeout 60
 /-    /etc/auto.foo  --timeout 60
```

auto.home:

```
 jwells -rw,noquota,intr server:/vol/home/jwells
 ... <SOME of these>
```

auto.foo:

```
 /foo/path/one -rw,noquota,intr server1:/path
 ... <LOTS of these>
```

When I start `autofs`, EVERYTHING in `auto.foo` gets mounted.  Thousands of mounts.  `/home` doesn't exhibit this.

I have various symlinks in my filesystem from `/some/place`->`/foo/mounted/path`, but certainly nothing constantly trolling all the paths to force them to automount.

I can force these to unmount, but explicitly umounting them, but they eventually show up again.

(Debian, Wheezy)